# How to conditionally execute many similar repeating lines of code in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I have no idea how to really phrase this question without showing my code, I'm sorry for the vague title. I have two blocks of code that I need to find a way to simplify. I don't know what to do, because to my knowledge, I can't just replace the numbers with an iterator and use a for loop. I want to repeat this to 100 cases with the same pattern. I very much don't want to type all this out, even copy-pasting sounds like a nightmare. Is there any way at all to repeat this using loops?

Thank you :)

```java
switch (count) {
    case 1: {
        binding1 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue1", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        binding1 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue1", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
        binding2 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue2", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        binding1 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue1", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
        binding2 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue2", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
        binding3 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue3", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
        break;
    }
}
```

```java
switch (hotkeyConfig.bindingCount) {
    case 1:
        while (binding1.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue1);
        }
    case 2:
        while (binding1.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue1);
        }
        while (binding2.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue2);
        }
    case 3:
        while (binding1.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue1);
        }
        while (binding2.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue2);
        }
        while (binding3.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue3);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is the order of the `while` statements - in the second code block - important? Or can `while (binding3.wasPressed())` come before `while (binding2.wasPressed())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first code block, just reverse the order of the individual `case`s and allow "fall through":

```java
switch (count) {
    case 3: {
        binding3 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue3", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
    }
    case 2: {
        binding2 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue2", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
    }
    case 1: {
        binding1 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue1", InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey"));
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also reduce the above code by writing a `createKeyBinding` method:

```java
public KeyBinding createKeyBinding(int index) {
    return new KeyBinding("key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue" + index, InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, "key.category.hotkey")
}
```

Then the first block of code becomes:

```java
switch (count) {
    case 3: {
        binding3 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(createKeyBinding(3));
    }
    case 2: {
        binding2 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(createKeyBinding(2));
    }
    case 1: {
        binding1 = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(createKeyBinding(1));
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an array rather than individual variables.
Note that since I could not ascertain the type for the variables, such as `binding3`, I use `Object` as the type.

```java
Object[] bindings = new Object[count];
for (int i = count; --i >= 0;) {
    bindings[i] = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(createKeyBinding(i));
}
```

The same can be applied to the second code block – assuming that the order of the `while` statements is not important, i.e.

```java
switch (hotkeyConfig.bindingCount) {
    case 3:
        while (binding3.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue3);
        }
    case 2:
        while (binding2.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue2);
        }
    case 1:
        while (binding1.wasPressed()) {
            client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValue1);
        }
}
```

However, if the order is important, then if you use an array (as shown above), the second code block can be written as:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < hotkeyConfig.bindingCount; i++) {
    while (bindings[i].wasPressed()) {
        client.player.sendCommand(hotkeyConfig.bindValues[i]); // assumes appropriate array
    }
}
```

Comment: Using fall-through is the same as long as the *order* of execution doesn't matter (probably the case).

Comment: @Bohemian the first code block appears to me that order is not important however not so clear for the second code block, hence my [stated] assumption that the order is not important for the second code block as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You definitely put me on the right track! My program has a class, hotkeyConfig, that stores the commands bound to the hotkeys in a json file between runs, and lets user edit them. The two blocks I posted were in my other main class. The first block is ran once to register everything. The second is ran every tick to check for bindings. It appears that if I use an array to store the commands, they aren't saved properly, but I can use a loop to store the `binding1,2,3` in main. I also didn't know you could omit `break` and have it run every case, that's useful. Thank you!

Comment: @Abra I tried upvoting but I don't have enough rep :/
I'll go back and upvote it once I get enough. I wasn't aware there was an "accept answer" thing on stackoverflow, I'm very new lmao but googled and accepted. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use an array, instead of three separate variables, for your `binding1, binding2, binding3`.  It might look something like this - I'm kind of guessing at what the classes involved might be.

```
KeyBinding[] bindings = new KeyBinding[3];
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    bindings[index] = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(
        new KeyBinding(
            "key.lightningtow.hotkey_keyValue" + (index + 1),
            InputUtil.Type.KEYSYM, 
            GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN, 
            "key.category.hotkey"));
}
```

and if you have your hot key config bind values in a similar array, your second snippet might look like this.

```
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    while (bindings[index].wasPressed()) {
        client.player.sendCommand(hotKeyConfigBindValue[index]);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you didn't intend to omit the `break` statements from your second excerpt.